# Выбор нескольких провайдеров подсказки в API Yandex Map

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Имеется карта на которой нанесены полигоны и поиск который ищет по этим полигонам, в строку поиска подставляются подсказки из созданного провайдера, как сделать так, что бы в случае если по собственному провайдеру ничего не находится то в дело включался провайдер "yandex#map", то есть подставлялись подсказки с адресами?

Код примера:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Многоугольник</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=3261ce08-c60a-4114-96f8-ce820abf124a" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init() {
      // Создаем список (массив) подсказок
      var podskazki = [

        "ТОС «Виктория»",
        "ТОС «Максимум Света»",

      ];
      // выполняем поиск по подсказкам
      var find = function(podskazki, find) {
        return podskazki.filter(function(value) {
          return (value + "").toLowerCase().indexOf(find.toLowerCase()) != -1;
        });
      };
      // создаем провайдер поиска 
      var myProvider = {
        suggest: function(request, options) {
          var res = find(podskazki, request),
            arrayResult = [5],
            results = Math.min(options.results, res.length);
          for (var i = 0; i < results; i++) {
            arrayResult.push({
              displayName: res[i],
              value: res[i]
            })
          }
          return ymaps.vow.resolve(arrayResult);
        }
      }
      // Создание подсказок в поиске
      var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('poisk', {

        provider: myProvider,
        noSuggestPanel: false,
        boundedBy: [
          [48.61, 134.98],
          [48.31, 135.29]
        ],
        strictBounds: true,
        results: 19

      });

      // поиск по выбору подсказки                 
      suggestView.events.add('select', function() {
        Search()
      })

      // поиск по Enter
      $("#poisk").keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          Search()
        }
      });
      // поиск по нажатию "лупы"
      $('.custom-search').click(() => {
        if ($('#poisk').val() != undefined) {
          Search()
        }
      });

      // Непосредственно поиск в панели
      function Search() {
        var request = $('#poisk').val();
        searchControl.search(request);
      }

      // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с заданным id ("map")
      var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
          center: [48.48, 135.08],
          zoom: 14,
          controls: ['zoomControl', 'typeSelector', 'fullscreenControl', 'searchControl'] // "Элементы управления (Зум, слои, фулскрин, поиск)

        }, { // Ограничение области карты Хабаровск + загород 
          restrictMapArea: [
            [48.61, 134.98],
            [48.31, 135.29]
          ],
          // Ограничение зума
          minZoom: 10,
          maxZoom: 17
        }),

        // Создание полигонов и добавление их на карту.
        myObjects = ymaps.geoQuery({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [



            {
              type: 'Feature',
              geometry: {
                type: 'Polygon',
                coordinates: [
                  [
                    [48.4872099152, 135.044750889],
                    [48.4865858624, 135.045233687],
                    [48.4863005786, 135.044150075],
                    [48.4869567290, 135.043726286],
                    [48.4872099152, 135.044750889]
                  ]
                ]

              },
              options: {
                fillColor: '00bfbf', // Цвет заливки
                fillOpacity: 0.45, // Прозрачность заливки
                strokeColor: 'ff007f', // Цвет обводки
                strokeWidth: 2, // Толщина обводки
                strokeOpacity: 0.5, // Прозрачность обводки
                fildColor: "Кировский", // Кластер объекта 
                filtColor: "2020" // Год объекта

              },
              // Содержимое балуна
              properties: {
                balloonContentHeader: '<a href="https://khv27.ru/projects/territorialnoe-obshchestvennoe-samoupravlenie/reestr-tos/index.php?ELEMENT_ID=106497">ТОС «Виктория»</a>', // Заголовок 
                balloonContent: '<b>Председатель: </b>' + 'Савинов Е.А.<br/>' + '<b>Адрес: </b>' + 'ул. Казачья гора, дом 9-7<br/>' + '<b>Район: </b>' + 'Кировский<br/>' + '<b>Дата создания: </b>' + '10 февраля 2020<br/>' + '<b>Реализованные проекты: </b>' + 'НОВЫЙ ДВОР 2021<br/>', // Содержимое
                balloonContentFooter: 'Телефон: </b>' + '409144', // Футер 
                hintContent: "ТОС «Виктория»" // Подсказка объекта
              }
            },




            {
              type: 'Feature',
              geometry: {
                type: 'Polygon',
                coordinates: [
                  [
                    [48.5213356048, 135.106362622],
                    [48.5206620838, 135.107070725],
                    [48.5214817114, 135.108052414],
                    [48.5216670166, 135.107526701],
                    [48.5215850548, 135.106754225],
                    [48.5214638935, 135.106566470],
                    [48.5213356048, 135.106362622]
                  ]
                ]

              },
              options: {
                fillColor: '00bf00', // Цвет заливки
                fillOpacity: 0.45, // Прозрачность заливки
                strokeColor: 'ff007f', // Цвет обводки
                strokeWidth: 2, // Толщина обводки
                strokeOpacity: 0.5, // Прозрачность обводки
                fildColor: "Железнодорожный", // Кластер объекта 
                filtColor: "2020" // Год объекта

              },
              // Содержимое балуна
              properties: {
                balloonContentHeader: '<a href="https://khv27.ru/projects/territorialnoe-obshchestvennoe-samoupravlenie/reestr-tos/index.php?ELEMENT_ID=106500">ТОС «Максимум Света»</a>', // Заголовок 
                balloonContent: '<b>Председатель: </b>' + 'Сергеев М.С.<br/>' + '<b>Адрес: </b>' + 'пер. Краснодарский, дом 19а<br/>' + '<b>Район: </b>' + 'Железнодорожный<br/>' + '<b>Дата создания: </b>' + '11 февраля 2020<br/>' + '<b>Реализованные проекты: </b>' + 'Спортивная площадка<br/>', // Содержимое
                balloonContentFooter: 'Телефон: </b>' + '+7 (4212) 40-91-42', // Футер 
                hintContent: "ТОС «Максимум Света»" // Подсказка объекта
              }
            },
          ]


        }).addToMap(myMap);

      // Создаем коллекцию для поиска по названию объектов
      myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),

        // Создаем массив с данными.
        myPoints = [

          {
            coords: [48.4872099152, 135.044750889],
            text: 'ТОС «Виктория»'
          },

          {
            coords: [48.5213356048, 135.106362622],
            text: 'ТОС «Максимум Света»'
          },


        ];

      // создание поисковой строки
      searchControl = myMap.controls.get('searchControl');

      // настройка поисковой строки Яндекса
      searchControl.options.set({
        provider: new CustomSearchProvider(myPoints),
        noPlacemark: true,
        placeholderContent: 'Введите адввврес ТОСа',
        boundedBy: [
          [48.61, 134.98],
          [48.31, 135.29]
        ],
        strictBounds: true,
        results: 10, //  требуемое количество результатов 
        resultsPerPage: 5,
        position: {
          left: -400 //  смещение строки поиска
        }
      });


      // Проверим попадание результата поиска в один из ТОСов.
      searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function(e) {
        highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[e.get('index')]);
      });

      // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта и находим полигон.
      function highlightResult(obj) {
        // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта.
        var coords = obj.geometry.getCoordinates(),
          // Находим полигон, в который входят переданные координаты.
          polygon = myObjects.searchContaining(coords).get(0);

        if (polygon) {
          polygon.options.set('fillOpacity', 0.2);
          polygon.balloon.open();
        }
      }

      // Провайдер данных осуществляет поиск геообъектов по массиву points.                        
      function CustomSearchProvider(points) {
        this.points = points;
      }

      // Провайдер ищет по полю text стандартным методом String.ptototype.indexOf.
      CustomSearchProvider.prototype.geocode = function(request, options) {
        var deferred = new ymaps.vow.defer(),
          geoObjects = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(),
          // Сколько результатов нужно пропустить.
          offset = options.skip || 0,
          // Количество возвращаемых результатов.
          limit = options.results || 20;

        var points = [];
        // Ищем в свойстве text каждого элемента массива.
        for (var i = 0, l = this.points.length; i < l; i++) {
          var point = this.points[i];
          if (point.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            points.push(point);
          }
        }
        // При формировании ответа можно учитывать offset и limit.
        points = points.splice(offset, limit);
        // Добавляем точки в результирующую коллекцию.
        for (var i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
          var point = points[i],
            coords = point.coords,
            text = point.text;

          geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            name: text + '',
            description: text + 'description',
            boundedBy: [coords, coords]
          }));
        }

        deferred.resolve({
          // Геообъекты поисковой выдачи.
          geoObjects: geoObjects,
          // Метаинформация ответа.
          metaData: {
            geocoder: {
              // Строка обработанного запроса.
              request: request,
              // Количество найденных результатов.
              found: geoObjects.getLength(),
              // Количество возвращенных результатов.
              results: limit,
              // Начинает поиск сразу после нажатия Энтер
              skip: offset
            }
          }
        });

        // Возвращаем объект-обещание.
        return deferred.promise();

        searchControl.events.add('load', function(event) { // Проверяем, что это событие не "дозагрузки" результатов и по запросу найден хотя бы один результат.

          if (!event.get('skip') && searchControl.getResultsCount()) {
            searchControl.showResult(0);
          }
        });

      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="poisk" placeholder="Введите название ТОСа" autocomplete="off" style="margin-right: 0px;">
    <div class="custom-search">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом переключение можно встроить в следующий блок

```
  // поиск по Enter
  $("#poisk").keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      Search()
    }
```

Достаточно проверять наличие **items** в **state** **suggestView**:

```
if (suggestView.state.get('items').length == 0) {
  suggestView.options.set('provider',"yandex#map")
}
```

Возврата к кастомному провайдеру это не обеспечит и для поиска **yandex#map** нужно будет ещё хоть раз нажать любую букву. Но это уже другие вопросы.

Пример: https://jsbin.com/dabigaginu/edit?js,output

p.s.: обнулил прежде ваш массив. Вместо **arrayResult = [5]** указал **arrayResult = []**.

Comment: В принципе эту функцию можно в в любое место ответственное за поиск засунуть выходит. Получается провайдер если меняется то он таким и остается быть до перезагрузки, а как сделать его динамическую подмену? Типа при вводе каждого символа делать проверку сперва по своему провайдеру а потом уже если результатов 0 то подставлять стандартный?